# Unique rule is applied when editting a record in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Here is the validation rule:

```
'name'=>array(
        'Please enter customer\'s name'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Please enter customer\'s name'
        ),
        'Unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('nameIsUniqueForCompany'),
            'message' => 'Customer with these initials already exists'
        )
    ),  


public function initialsAreUniqueForCompany($data){

    $company_id = $this->data['Customer']['company_id'];
    $initials = $this->data['Customer']['initials'];

    if($this->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('initials'=>$initials, 'company_id'=>$company_id))))
    {
        return false;

    }
    return true;        
}
```

The problem is that the rule is applied to a current object. Let's say I want to update a customer named 'ABC', but I just change his phone number. The application will then look if the name ABC already exists and it will ofcourse find it and will not update.

any ideas?

Comment: The validation method you've posted doesn't match the rule name... you may want to update your question with the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is flawed:
By design your validation rule will always only work for add, not for edit.
On edit, you need to also take the current ID into consideration.

Check out my http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/07/maximum-power-for-your-validation-rules/ post. The part about uniqueness contains a working approach.
For you that means, using my enhanced unique validation method:

```
'name' => array(
    'validate' => array(
        'rule' => array('validateUnique', array('company_id')),
        'message' => 'Customer with these initials already exists',
    ),
),
```

Basically, you always submit the id on edit (via hidden form field - automatically done by baked forms anyway), and remove it from the find result by using "id != current" in your conditions:

```
$this->alias . '.id !=' => $id
```

Reasoning: The currently edited record should not trigger the validation rule error, of course :)

Comment: Thanks! Worked a charm, simple logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass something like this:

```
'email' => array(
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message'=>'This e-mail has been used already',
            'on'=>'create'
        )
)
```

There is a node 'on'=>'create' in the array, which apply the rule only when the record has been created. Ofcourse there is also 'on'=>'update' and this will apply when the record is updated.

For update validation you should consider custom rule where you are checking row id to be different.

Comment: I think this isn't OP's want

Answer (score 0):

**In your controller**

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->isPut() || $this->request->isPost()) {
        if ($this->YourModel->save()){
            // do what ever you want
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->YourModel->read(null, $id)    
    }
}
```

and in your **edit.ctp** file

```
echo $this->Form->create('YourModel');
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
```

please let me know if you found any problem, glad to help you.

Comment: POST or PUT, that doesn't make any difference for validation.

Comment: @ndm please check and then tell me, cake will validate the data accordingly i.e. your id should be set or not for editing a record. please set up a project and try my code above and tell me if it doesnot work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say. I said nothing about the ID, I just said that the HTTP method doesn't matter for validation.

Comment: @ndm But he is still kind of right. What he implicitly said with "better PUT then POST" is that the ID should not be omitted for that kind of validation to be possible. But the answer is still incomplete, though.

Comment: @mark Now that's a kinda far-fetched implication if you ask me :)

Comment: @ndm What i want to say is, it is better to use PUT request for editing a record instead of Post. see my update now have i done anything wrong now, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
'subscription_name' => array
                                (
                                        'required'=>true,
                                        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
                                        'message' => 'Please enter Package name.',
                                        'Unique'=>array(
                                        'rule'   => 'isUnique',
                                        'message'=>'package name is already exit..'
                                        )
                                ),
```